# VB.NET doesn't round numbers correctly?

Tags: vb.net, rounding-error

I'm testing the speed of some functions so I made a test to run the functions over and over again and I stored the results in an array. I needed them to be sorted by the size of the array I randomly generated. I generate 100 elements. Merge sort to the rescue! I used [this link to get me started](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaAlgorithmsMergesort/article.html).

The section of code I'm focusing on:

```
private void mergesort(int low, int high) {
// check if low is smaller then high, if not then the array is sorted
    if (low < high) {
      // Get the index of the element which is in the middle
      int middle = low + (high - low) / 2;
      // Sort the left side of the array
      mergesort(low, middle);
     // Sort the right side of the array
      mergesort(middle + 1, high);
     // Combine them both
      merge(low, middle, high);
   }
}
```

which translated to VB.NET is

```
    private sub mergesort(low as integer, high as integer)
    ' check if low is smaller then high, if not then the array is sorted
        if (low < high)
      ' Get the index of the element which is in the middle
          dim middle as integer = low + (high - low) / 2
      ' Sort the left side of the array
          mergesort(low, middle)
      ' Sort the right side of the array
          mergesort(middle + 1, high)
      ' Combine them both
          merge(low, middle, high)
    end if
end sub
```

Of more importance the LOC that only matters to this question is

```
dim middle as integer = low + (high - low) / 2
```

In case you wanna see how merge sort is gonna run this baby

```
high   low                     high   low
100     0                      10      0
50      0                       6      4
25      0                       5      4
12      0                      12      7
6       0                      10      7
3       0                       8      7
2       0                  :stackoverflow error:
```

The error comes from the fact 7 + (8 - 7) / 2 = 8. You'll see 7 and 8 get passed in to mergesort(low, middle) and then we infinite loop. Now earlier in the sort you see a comparison like this again. At 5 and 4. 4 + (5 - 4) / 2 = 4. So essentially for 5 and 4 it becomes 4 + (1) / 2 = 4.5 = 4. For 8 and 7 though it's 7 + (1) / 2 = 7.5 = 8. Remember the numbers are typecasted to an int.

Maybe I'm just using a bad implementation of it or my typecasting is wrong, but my question is: Shouldn't this be a red flag signaling something isn't right with the rounding that's occuring?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you implementing your own sort instead of using the various built-in sort routines?  Is it the sort routines whose speed you are testing?

Comment: I'm sorting an object with three variables. One is the size of the array created in the test so instead having to type the comparator code for the built-in sorts I went and got one I'm already familiar with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without understanding the whole algorithm, note that VB.NET `/` is different than C# `/`. The latter has integer division by default, if you want to truncate decimal places also in VB.NET you have to use `\`.

Read: [\ Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e16fywh.aspx)

So i think that this is what you want:

```
Dim middle as Int32 = low + (high - low) \ 2
```

Comment: Wow. Didn't even know \ was an operator in VB.NET.

Comment: @Luminous: i learned it only when i've missed the C# behaviour in VB. The default in VB is the "natural": `3/2=1.5`, it returns always a `Double`. That's why this doesn't even compile: `Dim i As Int32 = 3 / 2`

Comment: Huh, in VB.NET dim i as int32 = 3/2 compiles.
Here's a better question. Why does dim foo as integer = 7+(8-7)/2 = 8 and dim foo = int(7+(8-7)/2 = 7?

Comment: @Luminous: it compiles only if you've set `Option Strict` to `OFF`. **Never** do this! You should always set it to `On`. Then you are forced to use VB.NET in the similar way as C#. Otherwise you'll get implicit conversions that you don't want or don't understand.

Comment: Oh now I see it. Option Strict was set to custom for some reason in the properties. Which is kinda funny since you can still bypass it by setting the configurations.

Comment: @Luminous: you can set it under Extras->[Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f33da8d.aspx)->Projects->VB-Standard

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in your diagnosis: there's something inconsistent with the rounding that's occurring, but this is entirely expected if you know where to look.

From the [VB.NET documentation on the `/` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25bswc76.aspx):

> Divides two numbers and returns a floating-point result.

This documentation explicitly states that , if `x` and `y` are integral types, `x / y` returns a `Double`. So, `5 / 2` in VB.NET  would be expected to be `2.5`.

From the [C# documentation on the `/` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b1ff23f.aspx):

> All numeric types have predefined division operators.

And further down the page:

> When you divide two integers, the result is always an integer.

In the case of C#, if `x` and `y` are integers, `x / y` returns an integer (rounded down). `5 / 2` in C# is expected to return `2`.